# Subharmonic functions for algebraic graph theory

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

I am reading the proof of Lemma 8.7.1 of Algebraic Graph Theory written by Godsil and Royle, and have the following question:

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ nonnegative irreducible matrix. Here I guess it is sufficient to know that "$A$ being irreducible" implies that $(I+A)^{n-1}$ has all its entries positive. Detailed definition of irreducibility will be in attachment.

For every nonnegative vector $x\neq0$, define $F(x)=\min_{i:x_i\neq0} \frac{(Ax)_i}{x_i}$, as usual the underscript $i$ indicates row index. What makes me confused is that the authors claim that $F((I+A)^{n-1}x)\geq F(x)$ for all $x$.

All I know is that, for $x\neq0$, $(I+A)^{n-1}x$ has all its entries positive, therefore, it is equivalent to show that $\min_{i} \frac{(A(I+A)^{n-1}x)_i}{((I+A)^{n-1}x)_i}\geq \min_{i:x_i\neq0} \frac{(Ax)_i}{x_i}$.

I would be much indebted for any clues!

[image][image]

Comment: The idea I think is the following: since F(x) = min(...), where x are nonnegative vectors, let G(x) = F((I+A)^(n-1) x). Then G and F have the same domain however G restricts its search of the min to positive vectors, while F searches the min using nonnegative vectors (so the search of the min includes positve vectors plus all non zero vectors with at least one zero coordinate), therefore G(x)>=F(x), i.e. the min found by G must be equal or greater then the min found by F.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a non-negative $x \neq 0$.

Write $i_0 := \arg\min_{i: x_i \neq 0} \frac{(Ax)_i}{x_i}$.

Then, 
$$\begin{align*}
F((I + A)^{n - 1}x) 
&= \min_{i: ((I + A)^{n - 1}x)_i\neq 0} \frac{(A(I + A)^{n - 1}x)_i}{((I + A)^{n - 1}x)_i} \\
&= \min_{i} \frac{(A(I + A)^{n - 1}x)_i}{((I + A)^{n - 1}x)_i} \\
&= \min_{i} \frac{((I + A)^{n - 1}(Ax))_i}{((I + A)^{n - 1}x)_i} \\
&= \min_{i} \frac{\sum_{j=1}^n((I + A)^{n - 1})_{ij}(Ax)_j}{\sum_{j=1}^n((I + A)^{n - 1})_{ij}x_j} \\
&\geq \min_{i} \frac{\sum_{j: x_j \neq 0}((I + A)^{n - 1})_{ij}(Ax)_j}{\sum_{j: x_j \neq 0}((I + A)^{n - 1})_{ij}x_j} \\
&\geq \min_{i} \frac{\sum_{j: x_j \neq 0}((I + A)^{n - 1})_{ij}(Ax)_{i_0}}{\sum_{j: x_j \neq 0}((I + A)^{n - 1})_{ij}x_{i_0}} \\
&= \frac{(Ax)_{i_0}}{x_{i_0}} \\
&= F(x).
\end{align*}$$